# How to automatically create new worksheet based on a certain input

Tags: excel, vba

I have budgets of several departments and I need to send them details.

I have a master file with data validation, now I want to create multiple worksheets when I change or toggle with the data validation input. Is this possible?

I am currently doing it through the conventional way and it's tedious, taking the data to a separate worksheet, breaking the links saving to a separate workbook and then sending it over to the department.
[The image is what my data looks like, so I want a new sheet to be created for A2 with the data inputs remaining the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FMCL.png)

Comment: you can create them with code, but you need to specify the language that you want to use.

Comment: I prefer VBA code.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware `data validation` only *validates the input values*
see [Apply data validation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/apply-data-validation-to-cells-29fecbcc-d1b9-42c1-9d76-eff3ce5f7249) and [More on data validation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/more-on-data-validation-f38dee73-9900-4ca6-9301-8a5f6e1f0c4c).

You can create worksheets with certain inputs using [VBA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/getting-started-with-vba-in-office), I am not fluent, so you can check this [example](https://www.get-digital-help.com/quicky-create-new-sheets-vba/)

You could also build a program that would create or modify Excel workbooks.

If you give an example of what you need with more detail maybe someone can help you further.

Comment: For instance, I have around 4 departments. I have prepared the master sheet. Now when I toggle to department 1, its respective numbers gets pulled out. Now I want to send this to department 1 and so on. Need a faster way to do this.

Comment: by "toggle to department" you mean a cell with data validation that has combo box?
and they are pulled out from where? the master sheet? and where is the toggle?
You should edit the main question so others can easily see. maybe copy your workbook, and delete any sensitive info from the copy, just leave the selection toggle and a few example data and show screen shots of what you have and explain what you desire you can also show a hand made result example of what you expect the automation to do.